How can I resolve the problem Unknown Kotlin JVM target?
When I try to build my project in Android Studio, I get the following errors:
Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.


Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 1s
I actually didn't try anything, yet. I am looking for the answers here.
